# HTACCESS redirect always to /

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect always to /.
For example if my URL is http://link.com/tag/////// it should be redirected to http://link.com/tag////// (all slashs should be removed ant leave only one). How to do that? I'm using CodeIgniter, my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule at the top **before other rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)/{2,}[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: no, the "tag" was only the example, my link can be `http://link.com/tag/antother_uri/the_other_segment//// ` or `http://link.com/tag/the_other_segment///////////////`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this right below `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\ \?]+?)/{2,}([^\ \?]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: that works, but if my url is `http://link.com/uri1/uri2/uri3///////////////////////` i see error that the redirect cycle is infinity